# Need to sum field from result set in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, variables

I have item 200400 that is stocked at 6 different locations.

Each location has a minimum number they keep in stock, a quantity on hand and quantity on order.

Only one of these stores can order the item (mfg store).  So I need to add the NeedToStockToStore results into one field

I will then use that calculated field to subtract the mfg stores order quantity to see if the store is over ordering.

So I want my result set to be the same as it is now(below) but have one more column for called OnOrderCheck – all rows will be NULL expect for store 3 where it would say 1

Because mfg store ordered 6 but they only needed to order 5 so they have ordered 1 to many.

```
 item        desc        store   store_min  store_max  on_hand  on_order  mfg store NeedToStockToStore
200400     SVAssembly      1        1         1         0        0         3        1
200400     SVAssembly      2        1         1         0        0         3        1
200400     SVAssembly      3        1         1         0        6         3        1
200400     SVAssembly      5        1         1         0        0         3        1
200400     SVAssembly      7        1         1         1        0         3        0
200400     SVAssembly      8        1         1         0        0         3        1
```

This is the SQL Code I am using to retrieve the above information:

```
 SELECT T0.[ItemCode],
       T0.[ItemName],
       T2.[WhsCode]  as [Whse],
       T2.[MinStock] as [Store Min],
       T2.[MaxStock] as [Store Max],
       T2.[OnHand],
       T2.[OnOrder]  as [On PO],
       T0.[MinLevel] as [Corp Min],
       T0.[MaxLevel] as [Corp Max],
       T0.U_MFGSite,
       MAX(CASE
             WHEN T2.[WhsCode] = T0.[U_MFGSite] THEN T2.[MinStock] - T2.[OnHand]
             ELSE ( CASE
                      WHEN T2.[OnHand] < T2.[MinStock] THEN
                      ( T2.[MinStock] - (
                        T2.[OnHand] + T2.[OnOrder] ) )
                      ELSE 0
                    END )
           END)      as NeedToStockToStore
FROM   asap.dbo.OITM T0
       INNER JOIN asap.dbo.OITW T2
         ON T0.ItemCode = T2.ItemCode
WHERE  t0.itemcode = '200400'
       and t2.minstock <> 0
       and t2.maxstock <> 0
group  by T0.[ItemCode],
          T0.[ItemName],
          T2.[WhsCode],
          T2.[MinStock],
          T2.[MaxStock],
          T2.[OnHand],
          T2.[OnOrder],
          T0.[MinLevel],
          T0.[MaxLevel],
          t0.U_mfgsite
```

Comment: What exactly are you asking? Which column needs to be summed?

Comment: I am asking how do I sum the last column in the result set so I can use it for another calculation

Comment: What RDBMS? The square brackets look like SQL Server but what version? Also how do you want this `SUM`? As an extra row or extra column?

Comment: ignore the [ ] - they do note need to be there, they are irrilivent to the issue.

Comment: I need the sum to be a result in a new column

Comment: I am using SQL Server 2008 R2

Comment: You could use a CASE construct to check if mfg store = store id and output the difference of 'on order' and 'need to stock to store'

Comment: Why is this 9 month old question being edited and commented on?

Answer (score 0):

WITH ROLLUP would work great for what you are trying to achieve.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-group-by-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017#group-by-rollup

```
 SELECT T0.[ItemCode],
       T0.[ItemName],
       T2.[WhsCode]  as [Whse],
       T2.[MinStock] as [Store Min],
       T2.[MaxStock] as [Store Max],
       T2.[OnHand],
       T2.[OnOrder]  as [On PO],
       T0.[MinLevel] as [Corp Min],
       T0.[MaxLevel] as [Corp Max],
       T0.U_MFGSite,
       MAX(CASE
             WHEN T2.[WhsCode] = T0.[U_MFGSite] THEN T2.[MinStock] - T2.[OnHand]
             ELSE ( CASE
                      WHEN T2.[OnHand] < T2.[MinStock] THEN
                      ( T2.[MinStock] - (
                        T2.[OnHand] + T2.[OnOrder] ) )
                      ELSE 0
                    END )
           END)      as NeedToStockToStore
FROM   asap.dbo.OITM T0
       INNER JOIN asap.dbo.OITW T2
         ON T0.ItemCode = T2.ItemCode
WHERE  t0.itemcode = '200400'
       and t2.minstock <> 0
       and t2.maxstock <> 0
group  by T0.[ItemCode],
          T0.[ItemName],
          T2.[WhsCode],
          T2.[MinStock],
          T2.[MaxStock],
          T2.[OnHand],
          T2.[OnOrder],
          T0.[MinLevel],
          T0.[MaxLevel],
          t0.U_mfgsite WITH ROLLUP
```